# Link a JSON file and a java file

Tags: java, android, json, database

I recently started to code a java application only I am stuck on the json file. I followed the youtube video of Coding in Flow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2xtLqP8dSQ
So I followed all the steps and in the end I have similar files to it and yet no results at the end.

Java file

```
package com.example.xxxxx;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class bookprofile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bookprofile);
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });
    }
    private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "http://31.207.38.60/one.json";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("emmployees");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String firstName = employee.getString("firstname");
                                int age = employee.getInt("age");
                                String mail = employee.getString("mail");
                                mTextViewResult.append(firstName + ", " + String.valueOf(age) + ", " + mail + "\n\n");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.xxxxx.bookprofile">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_parse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="parse" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please, I've been thinking about it for 4 hours. I'm going to be crazy. xd

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("employees");


It doesn't solve the problem but like that you know it's not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this library to get an Array or Json object is often difficult.
For convenience, it is better to take the JsonObject as a string and parse it.

For Example:

`StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    parseString(response);
                }
            }
        }....`

In addition, the text of your file is not an object but an array, so it should be received as an array:

```
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            response.get(....)
        }
    })
}
```